# Matching basic HTML using regex (or any other way)

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have some HTML as follows:

```
    <b>This is a title: </b> 0091 + Two + 423 + Four + (Five, Six, Seven)
    <b>Some more text: </b> Abc + Hi + Random + Text + (Hello, 522, Four)
    ...
    <b>Hello world!: </b> Test + Foo + 1122 + (120, 122, Four)
```

Now, using `php`, I want to split this and make two arrays as follows:

**Array 1** - (This will have everything in the `<b>` tags)

```
    [0] -> <b>This is a title: </b>
    [1] -> <b>Some more text: </b>
    ...
    [n] -> <b>Hello world!: </b>
```

**Array 2** - (This will have everything *outside* the `<b>` tags)

```
    [0] -> 0091 + Two + 423 + Four + (Five, Six, Seven)
    [1] -> Abc + Hi + Random + Text + (Hello, 522, Four)
    ...
    [n] -> Test + Foo + 1122 + (120, 122, Four)
```

I tried to use regular expressions and `preg_match_all` but I just can't seem to figure them out. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Hi Andy! I am already using the `simple_html_dom` library (which is mentioned in the link you posted). I was having a tough time with this string especially and I decided to go the regular expression route. Just for this case. Otherwise I am using an HTML parser library for the rest. Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$string = '    <b>This is a title: </b> 0091 + Two + 423 + Four + (Five, Six, Seven)
    <b>Some more text: </b> Abc + Hi + Random + Text + (Hello, 522, Four)
    ...
    <b>Hello world!: </b> Test + Foo + 1122 + (120, 122, Four)';
preg_match_all("#(<b>[^<]+<\/b>)([^<]+)#", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <b>This is a title: </b> 0091 + Two + 423 + Four + (Five, Six, Seven)

            [1] => <b>Some more text: </b> Abc + Hi + Random + Text + (Hello, 522, Four)
    ...

            [2] => <b>Hello world!: </b> Test + Foo + 1122 + (120, 122, Four)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <b>This is a title: </b>
            [1] => <b>Some more text: </b>
            [2] => <b>Hello world!: </b>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  0091 + Two + 423 + Four + (Five, Six, Seven)

            [1] =>  Abc + Hi + Random + Text + (Hello, 522, Four)
    ...

            [2] =>  Test + Foo + 1122 + (120, 122, Four)
        )

)
```

Comment: Akram, this worked perfect! Thanks a lot. :) Any good recommendations where I can learn more about regex?

Comment: just try to do it yourself, regex is nice to learn... search google

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<pre>
<?php

$subject =<<<LOD
<b>This is a title: </b> 0091 + Two + 423 + Four + (Five, Six, Seven)
<b>Some more text: </b> Abc + Hi + Random + Text + (Hello, 522, Four)
<b>Hello world!: </b> Test + Foo + 1122 + (120, 122, Four)
LOD;

$pattern = '~(<b>.*?</b>)((?>[^<]+|<(?!b))*)~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

array_shift($matches);
array_walk_recursive($matches,function (&$val){ $val=trim($val); });
list($array1, $array2) = $matches;

print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
```